# Configuring session-timeout Programmatically JBOSS EAP 6.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

Is it possible to configure the session-timeout Programmatically in JBOSS EAP 6.1? Using @PostConstruct on session scoped beans or is there any listeners for Session creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HttpSession#setMaxInactiveInterval](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29). Then you can have a class which will implement `HttpSessionListener` interface so whenever new session is created, you can programatically set new timeout to it.

```
public class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(yourInterval); 
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event){
    }
}
```

As far as I know, there is now way how to do this in `CDI` but `Servlets` and `CDI` are compliant technologies so it should work together. Note that you can inject any `CDI` bean to this listener.

Comment: Hi, this works like a charm for http, does this also work incase of https/ssl? I will accept the answer

Comment: To be honest - I don't know. Try that and let me know whether it works.